# Php pdo combine tables to create new table

Tags: php, pdo, datatable, insert, left-join

I am not sure best way to handle this situation.  A user can upload a video but when the video is uploaded I need to be able to add the movie name and every user in the database to a table.  That way I can tell which users have seen the new video and which ones have not.

Not sure I'm explaining this very well.  Basic I have a firm where users can upload videos and they are added to a table. I have another table that let's me know what videos users have watched.  I need to be able to add the new videos to each user into the watched database so I know who has seen the new video and who has not.

Any tips on the best way to handle this would be much appreciated thank you in advance.

Comment: Only add a link between user and video WHEN a user views the video

Comment: The "default" situation is "not watched". When user watch, then you mark as "watched"

Comment: My problem is that u have to display the videos they have not watched and a separate spot displays what they have watched.  I tried left join which woks but instead of showing the information it's null so the list dot not acutely show.  How would I do it so the information is acutely displayed.  I know there has to be a way maybe compare the two tables and display where movie_name is not with that user but I can not find any information on that.